# How can I remove apps tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

How do I remove apps tabs in Google Chrome?

[image]

By the way, those two app tabs are empty. I have already tried to <kbd>right click</kbd> on them, but that didn't work. I have also tried dragging them away, but I couldn't drag them at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Chrome (v38 as of writing), these tabs will disappear automatically as long as all of your apps are on the first (leftmost) app page.